# How to update my android app

Tags: android

I am sure this is a simple answer but:

I want to update my android app that is already on the play market. If I upload a new .apk with the same keystore and package name will the play store automatically inform the user of a new update or is there something I need to do those types of notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Manifest, you need to change the build number.
If you don't, it will be rejected anyway by the play store.

Comment: @dtrodriguez Yes it will.

Comment: Yes that should do it.